Startx resource temporarily unavailable
I am attempting to start an xorg server with the command startx. The output tells me "radeon failed to allocate buffer", "radeon: size: 4096 bytes", "radeon: flags: 2" "radeon: alignment: 4096 bytes", and "radeon: domains: 2". This text repeats 4 times, at one instance saying the size is 524288 bytes. It ends saying "suspending AIGLX clients" and "xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable". My distro is Hyperbola, it is a fresh install, and my .xinitrc contains only the line "exec i3". What could be the cause of the error? Thanks
